# Which GPU is used when 2 gpus are available but no specific selections on them

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have two gpus installed in my pc as they are to be used in parallel (without any SLI or likes). Suppose I run a simple code in tensorflow like linear regression as in [this](https://github.com/golbin/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/03%20-%20TensorFlow%20Basic/03%20-%20Linear%20Regression.py). Then which gpu is used? Are both of them used? Here is run log.

```
2018-09-15 02:55:36.314345: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-09-15 02:55:36.675657: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705
pciBusID: 0000:17:00.0
totalMemory: 11.00GiB freeMemory: 9.08GiB
2018-09-15 02:55:36.798520: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705
pciBusID: 0000:65:00.0
totalMemory: 11.00GiB freeMemory: 9.08GiB
2018-09-15 02:55:36.799044: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2018-09-15 02:55:38.234984: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-15 02:55:38.235236: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971]      0 1 
2018-09-15 02:55:38.235392: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N N 
2018-09-15 02:55:38.235559: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:984] 1:   N N 
2018-09-15 02:55:38.235849: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 8783 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:17:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-09-15 02:55:38.601267: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 8783 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

Comment: Please post your code/error messages as text, not as an image, images are not searchable and thus don't make the question beneficial to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow's default is to consume the memory of all visible GPUs, but unless you code for using multiple GPUs only the first of the two will be used for computation.

You would typically set the environment variable `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0`prior to running python to limit tensorflow to only seeing gpu0, for example. (0=gpu0, 1=gpu1, etc, -1=cpu only)

Using both GPUs for computation requires that you code for multiple GPUs (and make decisions about what that means in your model), there are many tutorials on the topic, here's one quick one I pulled up: http://blog.s-schoener.com/2017-12-15-parallel-tensorflow-intro/